# What does empty() method do when we implement ArrayAccess interface in php?

Tags: php, arrayaccess

I am new to php and learning it from **[php.net](http://php.net)**. A **note** says on the following reference link that:

> When using empty() ArrayAccess::offsetGet() will be called and checked if empty only if **ArrayAccess::offsetExists()** returns **TRUE**.

What does it mean?

Reference link(http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this helps, way too many logic combinations don't always help though...

`empty()` is used to check if a value is considered 'empty', which means it either doesn't exist or the value is false (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

To be able to check this in a class implementing ArrayAccess (such as a class which allows array type access - using []), this means there are two stages to this process.

Firstly - does the element exist.  This is done by calling `offsetExists()` with the element your checking for.  So with `$data = [1,2];`, and you check element 2, `offsetExists()` will return false (only 0 and 1 have values) - which `empty()` will return true - as condition 1 (the item doesn't exist) is true.  Called for element 1, which does exist, `empty()` will return false (http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetexists.php).

Secondly if the item does exist, the second part of `empty()` says that it's also considered empty if the value is false.  `offsetGet()` will fetch the value from  the element you are testing.  So `$data[true,false]`, when `offsetGet()` is called for element 0, it will return the value at position 0 - which is the value true.  Condition 2 says if the value is false, which in this case is not the case and so `empty()` will return false.  But called for element 1, which has the value false, `empty()` will return true.

Comment: I came here because of the issue described in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62155, namely: what does empty() do *on* the object implementing ArrayAccess, not on the values it represents. Your description is just about the latter, while the question, if better formulated, could have been about the former. To answer the question to the former situation: it seems you can't use empty() or if ($obj) -tests to test for empty objects implementing ArrayAccess. You're stuck checking with count() or implementing your own "is_empty()" on the object...

Comment: @zmippie if you want to add that as an answer it may help others who like yourself may search for this.  But as you say *while the question, if better formulated, could have been about the former* would imply that the question doesn't ask about case you mention.

Answer (score 2):

In case you're wondering what happens on an object that *implements* `ArrayAccess` (which is not entirely clear from the question), then here's the deal: `empty()` or empty-like tests (e.g. `if ( $myObject ) ...` ) will always return TRUE, and there's nothing you can do about it.

This behavior is marked as "Not a bug" in PHP's bug tracker: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62155. The bug report is specifically about `Countable`, but in most situations `ArrayAccess` and `Countable` will both be implemented.

It is something to keep in mind when implementing `ArrayAccess` and/or `Countable`: it will be impossible to make your object behave exactly like an array.

For testing for empty you will have to resort to either:

1. Implementing your own "empty-like" function, e.g. `$myObject->isEmpty()`
2. Explicitly calling `count()` on the result (`Countable` will have to be implemented for this to make sense).